# How do I run my own code interacting with a browser?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, browser, userscripts

To make my life easy I'd like to run scripts in a browser and log the output. The two ways I have done it isn't a complete solution. The most recent thing I did was write a userscript to do `console.log` on AJAX post response, have an autohotkey script to mash buttons and then I copy/paste the results to a file. My biggest issue is [firefox collapses some lines on the console if they're very long](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39312066/how-do-i-stop-firefox-from-collapsing-long-console-messages). I'd try on chrome but [the userscript doesn't work on chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39279665/how-do-i-override-xmlhttprequest-in-chrome-userscript)

In the past I embed Firefox/Gecko in C# but I'm not sure how to capture post events and sometimes it feels like overkill.

What's the most simple way I can run a simple script in a browser and capture the results? Right now the idea solution might be modifying the userscript to POST the response to localhost where I write the response to a file and keep using the autohotkey script to produce the events. Does anyone have a better solution?

Answer (score 1):

For controlling web browsers from code, [selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/) is pretty good.

I also found [this component](https://github.com/lightbody/browsermob-proxy#using-with-selenium), which claims to work with selenium and give you HTTP traffic monitoring.